# ClearCase, a makefile use case

Tags: version-control, makefile, clearcase

I have an issue with the clearmake command in IBM ClearCase,
I use `clearmake` command to run my own makefile so i can build my program from the 'C' sourse code.

I want to put a command in make file, like `shell cleartool -some-command` to ignore all checkouts and all private files.

The disadvantage is that in config spec, i must include the command `element * CHECKEDOUT`.

But in  my use case i want to working with files and the same time i could make a compile/build with the old files, so i could work faster and i shouldn't change views or edit configspecs.

But my contemplation is, if i can ignore the checked outed files with a command, without to lose it.
Could you give me a solution ?

Comment: Is is possible for you to use 2 different snapshot views?

Comment: @VonC explain me, i am not sure but if this is the solution or if is usefull i could do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to working with files and the same time i could make a compile/build with the old files,

It would be easier to use two different snapshot views loaded on the disk at two different places.
In one (where no checkout has ever been done), you can set all files writables (through Windows, not ClearCase): all the files becomes hijacked, but modifiable, host for compilation/testing purposes.

In the other view, you keep your checked out files and your work in progress (but do not run your `clearmake`).